# How to give style to list item only if item has another <ul> inside otherwise style should not apply?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, css-selectors

How to give style to list item only if item has another list inside otherwise style should not apply? using css only.

See example here http://jsbin.com/udora

I want to remove arrows from all other items except "Articles" and "Pitching Past the 7th Inning"

I realized it's not possible with css any working jquery solution with demo?

Comment: Yeah... I'm not sure you can do this with pure CSS, but you can definitely do it with JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

What you have available in CSS (CSS-2 precisely) .. is `descendant selector` .. that is what others have been suggesting you ..
and that is also [from where(link)](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2003/10/19/styling-nested-lists/) you came up with this idea ..

The idea your searching for is called .. `Ascendant selector` .. (where you go for **the element which contains the particular element within**)
 which is unfortunately not available with CSS-2 but it has been proposed in CSS-3 .. 
Everywhere, they suggest to use classes and Ids as an alternative (which is more painful stuff .. in design and maintainance point of view ..) ... ultimately proving this is the handicap with CSS-2 ..

Comment: this article has something different

Comment: u wrote "not available with CSS-1 but it has been proposed in CSS-2 .. " yes tell me how we can do with any css2 property

Comment: uh...proposed for css2? hasn't css2 been out for a long time already? it's css3 that's still in the works.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the ul id and do something like this,

```
#sitemap>li>li {
    type: apply-style;
}
```

**EDIT:**

#sitemap>li means the li child of an element with id="sitemap"
and similarly, #sitemap>li>li means the li child of the li child of an element with id #sitemap.

read more about css selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#selectors)

**EDIT2:**

actually since the second li has to be under a second ul,

```
#sitemap>li>ul>li {
}
```

just keep in mind that > means direct child.

**NOTE:** This will not work in IE6.

Comment: A simpler version of this would be #sitemap li li (not quite the same however). Keep in mind using child selectors ">" won't work in Internet Explorer 6

Comment: i added example in question see it

Comment: @jitendra, ofc, you got a ul under the first li, so try this way,
#sitemap>li>ul>li {
}

Comment: u r not getting my question "How to give style to list item only if item has another list inside otherwise style should not apply?"

Comment: as of now, even in css3 I believe there is no way to get to the parent of an element, so if you want to select parent elements I think javascript is the way to go!

Comment: @Sujoy - You should state clearly that your solution will not work in IE6

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a css rule based on the descendants of the desired element.

But you could try applying the style to the inner ul, something like

```
li ul { foo: bar }
```

or if you need to not apply to 'Articles' then

```
li li ul { foo: bar }
```

Alternatively, in jquery you can say

```
$('li:has(ul)').css('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: but li li { foo: baz; } will be applied to second LI not first LI

Comment: Sorry, my original answer was way off.

Comment: So apply a style to all LI then remove it on the second one?

Comment: !important might come in handy

Comment: ur jquery solution not workin, it's working opposite what i want